# cannot find NSException in the following code

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios8

i m applying try catch to find the error, but unable to get exact reason of it.

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in subArray)
{

            Video *vid = [[Video alloc]init];
            [vid initwithDictionary:dict ];
        @try
        {
            [self.VideoArray addObject:vid];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"%@", exception);
        }

}
```

cannot find the reason of exception even after applying try-catch, while the code in Video Model file is given below.

```
 -(id)initwithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary*)dic{

if(self)
{

self.urlVedio1=[dic objectForKey:@"UrlVedio1"];
self.type_id=[dic objectForKey:@"type_id"];
}
return self;
}
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


 @interface Video : NSManagedObject

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * urlVedio1;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type_id;

 @end
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to initialize your object in `- (id)initWithDictionary:` method

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self)
  {
    self.urlVedio1=[dic objectForKey:@"UrlVedio1"];
    self.type_id=[dic objectForKey:@"type_id"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: let me try, i will give feedback

Comment: giving error, Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method of init family

Comment: in-fact cannot recognise selector setUrlVedio1:,

Comment: Does your method really named `initwithDictionary` (with the lower "w" character)?

Comment: rename it as `initWithDictionary` (with the upper "W" character)

Comment: About the assignment to 'self' outside of a method of init family?

Answer (score 1):

You can't intializer object like

Video *vid = [[Video alloc]init];

The docs for NSManagedObject state that the dedicated intializer is:

initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:

which is why that is failing. 
Error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Video'

So, Please use

AppDelegate *appdele= (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in subArray)
    {

```
    NSEntityDescription *VideoEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                        entityForName:@"Video"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:appdele.managedObjectContext];
    Video *vid =(Video*) [[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                    initWithEntity:VideoEntity
                                    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:appdele.managedObjectContext];

    [vid initwithDictionary:dict ];
    @try
    {
        [VideoArray addObject:vid];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", exception);
    }


    NSLog(@"%@", VideoArray);

}
```

Comment: or just subclass your video from NSObject class like this    @interface Video : NSObject its works :)